# Which Grows Faster: Factorial or Double Exponentiation

Tags: time-complexity

Which of the functions among $2^{3^n}$ or $n!$ grows faster?

I know that $n^n$ grows faster than $n!$ and $n!$ grows faster than $c^n$ where $c$ is a constant, but what is it in my case?

Comment: It isn't a proof, but evaluate the expressions with $n$ in the range 1 to 10 and see just how phenomenally fast $2^{3^n}$ grows compared to $n!$

Comment: Write down the values for 1 ≤ n ≤ 10. You can't? Why can't you?

Comment: Why is this in CS instead of [math.se]?

Comment: @Barmar because it's related to CS in terms of time complexity. Indeed, in this question, there is not a hard border between math and CS.

Comment: see [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation).

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You can find the result by taking a $\log$. Hence:

$$\log(2^{3^n}) = 3^n$$
$$\log(n!) \leqslant \log(n^n) = n\log n$$

(In the latter equation, we have used the fact that $n! \leqslant n^n$, as you note in the question.)

Of course $3^n$ grows faster than $n \log n$. 
As $\log$ is an increasing function, we can say $2^{3^{n}}$ grows faster than $n^n$, and also $n!$.

Comment: Beware, however, that $\log(f) = O(\log(g))$ does not imply $f = O(g)$, in general. For instance, take $f(n)=n^2$ and $g(n)=n$.

Comment: @chi You are right. But, it is true if $\log(f) = o(\log(g))$.

Comment: Another question related with taking log and solving and its danger is given in this link--> https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/117584/time-complexity-why-does-nn-grow-faster-than-n/117586#117586

Answer (score 26):

Another way to directly compare the two expressions is to take the ratio of consecutive terms:

$$\frac{2^{3^{n+1}}}{2^{3^n}}=2^{2\cdot 3^n}\gg 3^n\gg n+1=\frac{(n+1)!}{n!}$$

(for positive integers $n$), and clearly also $2^{3^1}=8>1!$, so $2^{3^n}$ indeed grows more rapidly than $n!$.

Comment: The discussion of $2^{3^1}$ is unnecessary.

Comment: @leftaroundabout, I guess that's true if you assume the >> signs are significantly greater than, but that's not very rigorous (and if they are only > signs it would then depend on your definition of "grows more rapidly")

Comment: Well, they only need to be “significantly” greater in a very weak sense, namely the ratio needs to be $>1+\varepsilon$. That is clearly given in this case, specifically $\frac{3^n}{n+1} > 1.5\quad \forall n>0$.

Answer (score 12):

You noted in your question that $n^n$ grows faster than $n!$, and that’s a great starting point for comparing the growth of $2^{3^n}$ and $n!$. Specifically, let’s ask - of $n^n$ and $2^{3^n}$, which grows faster?

To answer that, let’s try rewriting $n^n$ so that it has the same exponential base as $2^{3^n}$. Since $n = 2^{\log_2 n}$, we have that

$$n^n = (2^{\log_2 n})^n = 2^{n \log_2 n}.$$

Now, is it easier to see how $n^n$ and $2^{3^n}$ relate?

As a note, this approach is similar to taking the base-2 logs of both expressions. I thought it would be good to include this here because it gives a slightly different perspective on how to arrive at the answer given your initial observation.

Answer (score 2):

Induction.

Base case: $n=1$ gives $2^{3^1}=8$ and $1!=1$ which clearly holds.

Hypothesis: suppose that $2^{3^k}>k!$ for some $k\in\Bbb N$.

Consider $n=k+1$. Then $$2^{3^{k+1}}=2^{3^k\cdot3}>(k!)^3=(k+1)!\cdot\frac{k!(k-1)!}{1+\frac1k}>(k+1)!$$ which is true $\forall k>1$ and thus the result follows.

Comment: I tend to interpret "which grows faster?" questions as "whose big-Oh set is bigger?". With that interpretation, this post answers something different. (E.g. $x \mapsto x$ and $x \mapsto (x+1)$ are in the same big-Oh set, but in the spirit of this post the latter grows faster.)

Comment: @ComFreek I would really have to question that interpretation.  Which grows faster, $f(x) = x$ or $g(x) = 2x$?  I think by any reasonable meaning of the words "grow" and "faster", $2x$ grows faster than $x$.  My definition of *grows faster* would be $f(x)$ grows faster than $g(x)$ if there exists an $x_0$ beyond which $f'(x)$ is always greater than $g'(x)$.

Comment: That being said, this proof certainly doesn't prove anything about growth rates.  Plug in the functions $f(x) = -1/x$ and $g(x) = 0$ (on the domain $x > 0$) into your proof and you conclude that $g(x)$ grows faster than $f(x)$.  This is obviously wrong since $g(x)$ never grows and $f(x)$ never *doesn't* grow!